# Affect only One Div at a time - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i click on a div all the three div's change. I want only the div i clicked to be changed. 
I have this HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="vakkie">fkhakdhfkadh</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="vakkie">97309471094709</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="vakkie">****&&^%%%&%&$^$</div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.box {
    background-color: #a01414;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.vakkie {
    display: none;
    background-color: #00cbff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.box').toggle(
    function() {
        $('.vakkie').css('display', 'block');
    }, 
    function() {
        $('.vakkie').css('display', 'none');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $(this).find()

```
$('.box').toggle(function() {
$(this).find('.vakkie').css('display', 'block');
}, function() {
$(this).find('.vakkie').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: amazing how fast you guys help me out. Thanks! This is the right code for me

Answer (score 2):

All three are changing because you are using the `$('.vakkie')` querySelector, wich returns all elements with the class 'vakkie'. You should select '.vakkie' of the current box, you can do this by using the `this` keyword.

```
$('.box').toggle(function() {
    $(this).find('.vakkie').css('display', 'block');
}, function() {
   $(this).find('.vakkie').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)` - which refers to the jQuery object that was clicked:

```
$('.box').toggle(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'block'); // or $(this).show()
}, function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none'); // or $(this).hide()
});
```

In your case, `$(".vakkie")` targets all the elements having `.vakkie` class, and hence affects all of them. `this` refers to the HTMLObject clicked, which when wrapped in `$()` becomes the jQuery object.
Though, as RUJordan points out, use `this.style.display = "block"/"none"` as it does exactly the same thing with same length of code, and is faster.

Comment: `this.style.display = "block"/"none"` would also work. When using jQuery, it should be done sparingly as native JS is faster, and in most cases, just as easy to write.

Comment: @RUJordan I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expecting like this. Each box click, corresponding div should show?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/N5BYk/11/